# Linkedin API to get user Posts

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to **get a user posts or reposts by using their access token** via linkedin apis, but I am unable to get any data from api. Here is the api:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:vO2dw56SKV

Headers contains : my access_token as **Authorization**: Bearer <ACCESS_TOEKN> and **X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0
**
.THE response which I am getting is
{
"serviceErrorCode": 0,
"message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request",
"status": 400
}
Can anyone help me out with what is wrong with Syntax in API or am I even using correct api according to my requirement.

I am trying to find examples but unable to find from their docummentation

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to do it with the v2 of the API as I'm currently upgrading ours to the new API (their documentation is currently a bit mixed on whether v2 is expiring in February 2023, but I believe that it is).

I've managed to get it working using the 202301 version of their API (which is apparently required to get a list of posts). Which seems incredibly limiting given their new posts API (released middle of last year) doesn't provide the Id of a post when you create one.

This is particularly odd given LinkedIn used to provide the Id on creation, as do Facebook and Twitter. Also means that you're making an additional API call, to try and find the post you just made, and they modify the text you sent, so you can't match it on that to make sure you have the right one. I'll be raising a support ticket regarding this with LinkedIn, but here's the documentation I used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-06&tabs=curl#sample-request-2

This is the GET Url: [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{ORGIDHERE}&q=author&count=5](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A%7BORGIDHERE%7D&q=author&count=5)

This is part of the response I received back:

[image: Postman LinkedIn Response]

Comment: Turns out they sometimes include an id in the Response Header, other times elsewhere, in this case they do give the id in the Response Header, so you can grab it from there. Similar when uploading images to their new Image end points.

Comment: Hi, the OP says that need to get posts of a person. This works with organization but doesn't work on person post on this API.